# Secure way to send API key

Tags: api, security

I am developing an SDK which users would use to access my service
The authorization is done using an API key, which is unique to each user.
SDK makes API calls to my server using the provided API Key

My question is how do I secure the API Key passed in as a header in the API calls?
Should I encrypt the key while sending it over the network using RSA? But, then there will be two issues:

1. Shipping a public key with the SDK
2. Overhead of reading keys from file for every API call

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: use https .....

Comment: Who and what do you want to protect the key from? What is your thread model?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I want to protect the key from any of the network sniffers, who could get the plain text key and use it later

Comment: So why not use HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TLS (HTTPS). And then don't worry about the problem any further. TLS will protect all your network traffic - the only thing you need to worry about is checking the server's certificate (otherwise you could be sending the key to a network sniffer instead of a real server).